# In Filemaker Pro IWP, how do you force a text field to disallow carriage returns?

Tags: filemaker

I'm using Filemaker Pro's Instant Web Publishing feature. I've added a simple text field and button to a layout, set up tab ordering and the option that makes the field move to the next stop in the tab order when the user presses the "Enter" or "Return" keys. This works fine in Client mode, but when I try it through the web interface I have two problems.

First, the tab ordering is broken in web mode. More importantly, the text field I added accepts carriage return in web mode. I've searched fmforums.com and the documentation, but I can't find a way to disallow carriage returns when using IWP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version has improved support for tab order, so your first question may be fixed just by updating.

Unfortunately, the Carriage Return behaviour is tied to the browser's behaviour, so you are stuck with what you've got.

(Unless you go to custom web programming, of course!)

Answer (score 1):

If you validate the field to disallow the existence of carriage returns, I believe that submitting the form will produce an error for the user. The validation would be:

not PatternCount( MyField; "¶" )